# Optimize inserts

Tags: .net, mysql, sql-server

I did an importer in VB .Net witch get data from an SQLServer an inserts this data throught ADSL connection in a remote MySQL server.

in the first time, it was like 200 records, but now there are more than 500.000 records and it expends like 11hours exporting all the data and that is bad, veryyy bad.

I need to optimize my importer, witch now gets the data into a datatable an them i have a function witch with a loop (row to row) inserts the data with a "insert into" query...
like this:

```
            For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Console.Write(".")

            Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO clientes(id,nombrefis,nombrecom,direccion,codpos,municipio_id,telefono,fax,cif)" & _
                        "VALUES (@id,@nombrefis,@nombrecom,@direccion,@codpos,@municipio_id,@telefono,@fax,@cif)"
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cnn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", Int32.Parse(dr("ID EMPRESA").ToString))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nombrefis", dr("NOMEMP"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nombrecom", dr("EMPRESA"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("direccion", dr("DIRECC"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("codpos", dr("CODPOS"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("municipio_id", Int32.Parse(dr("CODIGO MUNICIPIO")).ToString)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("telefono", dr("TELEF"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fax", dr("FAX"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cif", dr("CIF"))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
```

any ideas or advices? 
thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create the command, add the parameters and prepare the command (`Prepare` method) before the loop. Then, in the loop, set the parameter values and execute the command
2. Execute the commands in transactions, by batches of 1000 or so commands

EDIT: I just realized you're using MySQL... So unless you're using an InnoDB table, you can't use transactions. Anyway, you can still use my first advice, so that the command is only prepared once

Comment: ey! Thank´s for your answer!

but the prepare method, would become my application faster?

and yes... my table type is MyISAM but i can change it if it would represent to become my application faster.

thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes, preparing the statements in advance would probably improve performance (at least slightly). I'm not so sure about the transaction, you will have to try it...